# Creating a 3 dimensional matrix from a matrix and vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `A` of size `p x p` and a vector `y = [y1,y2,...,yn]`.

What do I want to do is to create a 3 dimensional matrix of size `p x p x n`, that is, it contains `n` bands where each one is of size `p x p`.

**How each band is created?:**

Each band is equal to the matrix `A` multiplied by one value in `y`. For example, the first band is `A * y1`, the second band is `A * y2`. On the other hand, the band number `i`, where `i = 1, ..., n`, is equal to `A * yi`

Well, this can be easily done using a for loop, but this is trivial and expensive in computation. How can I prevent using a for loop? Is there any very fast automatic method that can directly create the 3-D matrix?

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `bsxfun` to multiply your `p x p` matrix by each value in `y`. We must reshape `y` to be `1 x 1 x n` though so that the multiplication creates a third dimension.

```
out = bsxfun(@times, A, reshape(y, 1, 1, []));
```

If you're on R2016b or newer (when MATLAB introduced implicit  broadcasting), you can replace `bsxfun` with simply `.*`

```
out = A .* reshape(y, 1, 1, []);
```

Comment: Thank you very much dear:))